# Login from cms page in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer-login

I have created a custom login page I have called it from cms page
CMS PAGE account_login

```
<div class="container"> {{block type="core/template" template="customer/form/cms_login.phtml"}}</div>
```

cms_login.phtml

```
<div class="login-form">
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/loginPost'); ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
        <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="form-control required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="form-control required-entry" id="pass" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Password')) ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
            </div>
        <div class="buttons-set">
          <button type="submit" class="login-btn" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
    var loginForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

I wanted to redirect to my cms page when there is wrong email or pass how I can I do can anyone help